# wp_customize set_transient except during preview

Tags: customization

So I'm using the `$wp_customize` to change many things in a theme, and as a result I'm wanting to set a transient for the generated CSS. I'm trying to find a flow that won't cache temporary results though, which is happening when a user plays around with settings and then hits "Cancel" - those results are still caching!

Right now I have a hacky method of setting the transient to live for just 1 second, but I feel there must be a better hook or something to grab onto. Here's my basic flow now:

```
    add_action( 'customize_register', array( $this, 'customize_register' ) );
    add_action( 'wp_head', array( $this, 'display_css_output' ), 99 );
    add_action( 'customize_preview_init', array( $this, 'css_cache_reset' ) );
```

`customize_register` takes care of all the settings.

```
function display_css_output( $short_life = 0 ) {
    $html = get_transient( 'my_custom_styles' );
    if ( empty( $html ) ) {
        $html = $this->generate_css_output();
        set_transient( 
            'my_custom_styles', 
            $html, 
            ( $short_life == 0 ? DAY_IN_SECONDS * 2 : 1 )
        );
    }
    echo $html;
}
```

This grabs transient if its set or otherwise goes through long process of generating the styles. Here also is my attempt at preventing the transient from persisting, `$short_life` which is included during another call to this function later.

```
function css_cache_reset() {
    delete_transient( 'my_custom_styles' );
    $this->display_css_output( $short_life = 1 );
}
```

There is the delete event and the call to make the transient only last 1 second.

Surely there is a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work, modifying the `display_css_output()` in this way:

```
function display_css_output() {
    $html = get_transient( 'my_custom_styles' );
    if ( empty( $html ) ) {
        $html = $this->generate_css_output();
        global $wp_customize;
        if ( ! isset( $wp_customize ) ) {
            set_transient( 'my_custom_styles', $html, DAY_IN_SECONDS );
        }
    }
    echo $html;
}
```

`$short_life` no longer needed. Basically check to see if `$wp_customize` is set, don't bother setting transient then.